# How do I end a conversation in BotFramework directline

Tags: botframework

Is there a way that I can mark a conversation as 'ended' on BotFramwork v4? I cannot find a way to end the session unless I restart the bot manually. There is no session expiry as well.
I am working on .net.
Is there a way to do it or some alternative to get the same output - separating users based on different users.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "separating users based on different users"? If you are using user data from conversationState and userState you shouldn't have to worry about conflicts between multiple users (though you would want to be careful of globally defined variables). Depending on exactly what you're trying to do, you may be able to set up a timeout on the webchat which you can handle in a onTurn function in your bot (e.g. you could delete conversationState to start over).

Comment: I am trying to identify users based on facial recognition. And ideally, every user should have a different 'session'. So every time a new user comes in front of cam, it should start a new session, with QnA specific to that user. And the session should get over either through a 'Thank You' intent or can be time based.